# Difference between using IEnumerator and using an array as an property

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, implementation, ienumerator

I get the idea of IEnumerator which gives an abilty of iteration to a class. I get the idea of why GetEnumerable() is needed to use foreach statement. But I wonder why I need to implement IEnumerator while I can declare an array as an property? I am really confused and could use a good explanation. Here is my codeblock, the result is the same with and without IEnumerator implementation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Customer customer1 = new Customer
        {
            Name = "Marty",
            Surname = "Bird",
            Id = 1
        };
        Customer customer2 = new Customer
        {
            Name = "Hellen",
            Surname = "Pierce",
            Id = 2
        };
        Customers customers = new Customers();
        customers.Add(customer1);
        customers.Add(customer2);
        //Using a property: This one works without an extra GetEnumerator implementation.
        foreach (var item in customers.CustomerList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
        //Using with GetEnumerator()
        foreach (Customer item in customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

    }
    class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    class Customers:IEnumerable
    {
        private List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();

        public List<Customer> CustomerList { get=> customerList; }
        public void Add(Customer p)
        {
            customerList.Add(p);
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return customerList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Who said that you need to implement `IEnumerator`?

Comment: The definition of foreach says so. If you want an iterable class, you need it to be inherited from either IEnumerator interface or from a class which is inherited from IEnumerator.

Comment: So if you want iterable class - you implement it. Usually you don't. You will need if you implement new collection/iterable types for some reason. Again, usually you don't, you just reuse existing ones.

Comment: @muaet Actually `foreach` just needs the thing you pass to it to have a `GenEnumerator` method that returns something with a `MoveNext` method and a `Current` property.

Comment: The `CustomerList` property is giving users of your class raw access to your private field, which isn't very good data encapsulation.  If you remove that field than you're left with access through the `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: @IceGlasses Yes, it seems like that in this example but it can be avoided by customizing getter's body i presume. The main thing that i wonder is what might go wrong if i use it like that, or can there be any optimization problems by using an array as an property?

Comment: Someone can call `Customers.CustomerList.Add()`, bypassing `Customers.Add()` and whatever logic motivated you to have a Customers class in the first place.  (Or they could Remove() or Insert() or whatever without Customers knowing that changes are happening.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need to implement IEnumerator at all. You can just get rid of the Customers class and replace the line:

```
Customers customers = new Customers();
```

with this:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customers>();
```

The only reason you were required to implement GetEnumerator was because you had inherited the class Customers from IEnumerable, which is an interface that declares that method. All methods and properties in an interface must be implemented in a class that implements that interface.

Just given the code you've shown you don't need the Customers class, just use a List as I explained above.

However, if you really need a Customers class, because you plan to add more functionality to it than what you've shown, one option would be to inherit from `List<Customer>`. Then it would work in the foreach statement without needing to implement GetEnumerable() because List already implements that method.

Comment: I see. It is easier to inherit from a class which already has implemented the IEnumerator. Let's say i need more functionality and need to use Customers class, is there a problem using an array as an property as it is already iterable?

Comment: No, it isn't a problem to use an array as a property, and either expose the IEnumerator through a method, or expose the array as a public property, etc., but it is really preference at that point. It depends on how you want to design your class, and how it will be used, etc. There is no definitive answer to that question without knowing the intention. The link provided in John Wu's answer provides some good guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Array properties often cause errors. We develop a reliable array property that avoids errors in foreach-loops. Microsoft suggests a design pattern that does not use the null value, even when there is no data.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (string item in Empty)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item); // Never reached
        }
    }

    /// Get an empty array.
    public static string[] Empty
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[0]; // Won't crash in foreach
        }
    }
}
```

NET has its IEnumerable interface misnamed - it should be IIterable. Basically a System.Collection.IEnumerable or (since generics) System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable allows you to use foreach on the object implementing these interfaces.IEnumerable, on the other hand, basically says that given a start position it is possible to get the next value. One example of this may be an infinite series of numbers:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Infinite()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
        yield return i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What kind of problems may occur if we use a list as a property?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to roll your own enumerable `Customers` class, it is very easy:

```
class Customers : List<Customer>
{
}
```

That's it!

Now you can do this:

```
Customer customer1 = new Customer
{
    Name = "Marty",
    Surname = "Bird",
    Id = 1
};
Customer customer2 = new Customer
{
    Name = "Hellen",
    Surname = "Pierce",
    Id = 2
};
Customers customers = new Customers();
customers.Add(customer1);
customers.Add(customer2);
foreach (var item in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

That being said, you may want to read this answer: [Is it a good practice to create your own collection class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/196133/115084). In most cases you can skip the special class and just use `List<Customer>` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get the idea. It is indeed practical. But can you tell me is there any solid reason to not use arrays as an property to get iterability? Optimization, performance or security it might be. Everyone suggest something, some of them very useful like yours but that doesn't answer the question bothering me ^^ Can you give an insight?

Answer (score 1):

It's because an array implements `GetEnumerator()`. Your class might not always store enumerable things in a data structure that already implements that for you though. You can get very creative as this pattern is extremely flexible.

Take this class as an example:

```
class Numbers1To5 : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() => new Numbers1To5Enumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    class Numbers1To5Enumerator : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        public int Current { get; private set; }
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (Current >= 5)
                return false;

            Current++;

            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Current = 0;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If you had a program that did the following, you'd get the numbers 1 through 5 displayed in the console:

```
foreach (int number in new Numbers1To5())
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Comment: So you are saying that if we need more complex iteration rules other than lists or arrays has, we could use implementation to customize. Right? What kind of iteration method we could declare diffrent than arrays already has i wonder?